# How to use a variable as input for the alignment in JLabel, Java

Tags: java, jlabel

I want to know how to pass variables through the JLabel alignment parameter. For example:

```
String myString = "CENTER";
JLabel label = new JLabel("text", JLabel.myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation of  javax.swing.SwingConstants [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/SwingConstants.java#SwingConstants.0LEFT) and
below are the respective values for LEFT, RIGHT, CENTER

```
public static final int LEFT    = 2;
public static final int RIGHT   = 4;
public static final int CENTER  = 0;
```

You can either take input as integer or convert your string input to these numbers using switch case of if and pass as second parameter to your JLabel constructor `JLabel(String text, int horizontalAlignment)`

Answer (score 0):

you can write a converter mathod something like this:

```
int getAlignmentFromString(String str){
        switch (str){
            case "CENTER":
                return SwingConstants.CENTER;
            case "LEFT":
                return SwingConstants.LEFT;
            case "RIGHT":
                return SwingConstants.RIGHT;
            case "LEADING":
                return SwingConstants.LEADING;
            case "TRAILING":
                return SwingConstants.TRAILING;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

and you can use this method for geting correct alignment value like this:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("text", getAlignmentFromString(myString));
```